# ipkg and apcupsd disappear after logging out of the session in which they are installed

Tags: synology, apc-smart-ups, apcupsd

I'm attempting to install apcupsd on 2 Synology NAS servers (RS3411 and RS3412) so that they shutdown when batterlife on the UPS (APC SmartUPS X 1500) reaches a set minimum.

Here is what I do:
- ssh into the NAS as root
- install ipkg (sh syno-i686-bootstrap_1.2-7_i686.xsh)
- instal apcupsd (ipkg install apcupsd_3.14.8-1_i686.ipk)
- configure apcupsd.conf
- start apcupsd
- check with apcaccess
So far so good, it works.
However, when I log out of the session (directly or by rebooting) apcupsd doesn't work anymore, reporting as not being installed. ipkg does the same. When I try to reinstall ipkg is reports that it can't. After removing 2 folders (/volume1/@optware and /usr/lib/ipkg) and can install again and it's back to square 1.

I have no good idea what happens here. It might be something is installed in a part of memory that is cleaned when closing the session but I haven't much of a clue.
As far as I can tell all files are installed on the disks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be [here](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=19378). Specifically step 10, it comes instead of the normal way but is, in practice, alike.